# minOccurs and maxOccurs

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am using apache cxf 3.1.8 and the wsdl is generated automatically by the cxf engine.
I want to set minOccurs and maxOccurs for the field ProductId,like below: 
Expected:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ProductId" type="xs:int"/>
```

Actual:

```
 <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProductId" type="xs:int"/>
```

In other word,I want the element ProductId must occur only once in my request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v1="http://nameSpace/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<getProductService>
    <arg0>
        <ProductDate>2016-04-01</ProductDate>
        <ProductId>prod1</ProductId>
        ##<ProductId>prod1</ProductId>##
    </arg0>
</getProductService>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My class Product is defined below :

```
public class Product{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@XmlElement(name = "ProductId")
protected int productId;
@XmlElement(name = "OperationType")
protected String operationType;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the question? You already have min and max occurs in the xsd

Comment: Thanks @Sridhar.i have edited my question to be clear.

Comment: Since the default value for `maxOccurs` is 1 there is not really a difference.

Comment: Thanks @Henry.but when i duplicate for example the field ProductId as shown in my request, i didn't get any error.So how can block the duplication?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable XML schema validation on server side at least, and possibly on client side if you want to detect malformed responses from the server as well.

In CXF, you enable schema validation with the `schema-validation-enabled` property on your jaxws client or endpoint (server-side) as described in [CXF FAQ](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint?). Also since CXF 2.3, you can use the `SchemaValidation` annotation in your code.

More examples on Glen Mazza's blog:
https://glenmazza.net/blog/entry/soap-xml-schema-validation